# ImportError: Cannot import name httputil

Tags: python

I hava two different files: **data_source** and **util**. I import **util**  at **data_source** like this:

```
from util import HttpUtil
```

But there is some error when I run

```
from util import HttpUtil
```

> ImportError: cannot import name HttpUtil

How can I solve this?

This is the directory structure of the module:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g0Cs.png)

In **util**

```
 class HttpUtil(object):

   @staticmethod   
   def request(host, port, method):
```

In **data_source**

```
import json  
import urllib   
import time   
from util import HttpUtil
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the contents of the file? I am assuming `data_source` is the script where you want to import `util`. Is util your personal module? Could you share the directory structure of the module? Have you installed it using `pip`?

Comment: is this HttpUtil is in Python system path ?

Comment: Do you have  a`__init__.py` file just in your `util` folder?

Comment: @raj  **data_source** and **util** are my personal module.

Comment: @VillageMonkey yes, HttpUtil is in Python system path

Comment: @vahdet There is not **__init__.py** in **util** module

Comment: Is the HttpUtil class in your __init__ file?

Comment: @raj, **HttpUtil** is not in my **init** file. But I try to import util in **init** file, the error still happens.

Comment: Did you install this module by going inside and doing `pip install .`

Comment: Can you import `util` directly: `import util`? You may be importing other `util` (it's really common module) which does not contain `HttpUtil`. Can you change the name of `util` to `util2` and check?

Comment: @Eypros Thanks you very much, when I change the name of _util_ to _util2_, there is no error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

- Do check if there really exists a HttpUtil function defined in utils. For instance, do watch out for spelling or casing errors.
- Post the .py files for reference, in case the error persists.

Comment: tks. I post more **.py** files

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in your directory? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) might be of help otherwise.

Comment: There is **__init__.py** in my directory